# Post-Flood Atmospheric Changes

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, parashat-noach, noach-noah-the-man

Rav Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld [quotes](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/YCPP.html) his grandfather who brings a Midrash saying that the world before the Flood didn't feature decay, therefore Noah didn't realize his grape juice was going to turn into wine since there was no bacteria fermentation before then. Where is this Midrash about the antediluvian atmospheric conditions?

Comment: I can’t track this down at the moment, but i know for a fact that this is a Maharal.

Comment: [This Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.5.4.1) introduces the idea of atmospheric changes after the flood affecting lifespan. The Chavel edition doesn't bring any source.

Comment: A quick search in Torah Sheleimah yielded no relevant results for the word אוירה